# При попытке подключиться или создать бд в kotlin выдаёт ошибку

Tags: kotlin

```
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLException
import java.sql.Statement

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:test.db"
    try {
        // Устанавливаем подключение к базе данных
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")
        val connection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl)
        // Создаем выражение для выполнения SQL-запросов
        val statement: Statement = connection.createStatement()
        // Создаем таблицу в базе данных
        val createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persons (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)"
        statement.execute(createTableQuery)
        // Закрываем ресурсы
        statement.close()
        connection.close()
        println("База данных успешно создана.")
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
        println(e.message)
    }
}
```

- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
- at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
- at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
- at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
- at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)

В external libraries я добавил sqlite connector 8.2.0-jar
В PATH пути не добавлял целый день ушёл на попытки что то сделать

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, проблема может быть связана с тем, что ты используешь неправильную версию библиотеки SQLite JDBC или что-то не так с конфигурацией проекта.

Попробуй использовать версию библиотеки SQLite JDBC, которая поддерживается твоей версией Kotlin и языка программирования в целом. Попробуй установить более стабильную версию, например:

implementation("org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.36.0.1")

Убедись, что в твоем проекте правильно настроены зависимости и библиотеки, и что они подключаются.

Проверь, правильно ли ты указал версию языка Kotlin в файле build.gradle.kts или build.gradle.

Убедись, что твой проект корректно зависит от Kotlin и использует соответствующую версию.

Если у тебя есть Gradle, попробуй выполнить следующую команду в терминале в корне проекта:

./gradlew clean build

Это очистит проект и пересоберет его с учетом новых зависимостей.

Если проблема сохраняется, возможно, стоит попробовать другие версии библиотеки SQLite JDBC или проверить документацию для твоей конкретной среды разработки или фреймворка.